# How to prevent a "keypress" event firing a "click" event when focus is on a button - javascript/html dom

Tags: javascript, events

I have a button that fires a "stopstart" function (animation). I also want to have a mouseless method to do this so I've bound the same function to the space bar. This works.

However *if focus is on the button*, and I press space - both events fire, can't work out how to stop this (the keypress event fires first - in chrome..)

Eventlistener code:

```
document.getElementById("stopstart").addEventListener("click",
        function (event) {
            stopstart();
        }); //add event listener to "stopstart" button  

document.addEventListener("keypress",
        function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 32) { //space key
                stopstart();
            }
        }); //add spacekey event listener to document
```

I don't want to remove focus from the button, as I'd like to retain that functionality - the two events appear to be separately generated - so I haven't found how to detect that the click event was in fact generated by the space bar.

Is this solvable using without having to add temporary flags to catch it etc

Comment: But the question is since the click code is triggered, why do you need both he keypress and the click when the click would just work fine? Seems like you need a work around for something that is already working with one event listener.

Comment: Please adapt this fiddle to reproduce the problem http://jsfiddle.net/4srzb/

Comment: I updated the fiddle to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4srzb/1/

Comment: It occurred to me (after posting) that I could capture the keypress event on the button eg by adding:

    `document.getElementById("stopstart").addEventListener("keypress",
        function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        }); //capture key action event`

I can prevent the keypress event bubbling up from the button - however I'm not sure if this will work in all browsers, all the time. It appears to work in chrome at the moment.. eg update fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4srzb/2/ -seems to work?

Comment: a `event.preventDefault();` should prevent the click event from firing.

Answer (score 3):

The click location for key events is zero, zero so you can look for that.

```
document.getElementById("stopstart").addEventListener("click",
    function (event) {
        var x = event.x || event.clientX;
        var y = event.y || event.clientY;
        if (!x && !y) {
            alert("key press");
            return false;
        }
        stopstart();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mScEC/

Comment: Can't see any way of telling the difference between the two for sure so I think this is the only way to go and the chance of a false positive is tiny

Answer (score 0):

````
     function (event) {
        if (event.pointerType !== "mouse") return;
         stopstart();
     }); //add event listener to "stopstart" button  

document.addEventListener("keypress",
     function (event) {
         if (event.keyCode === 32) { //space key
             stopstart();
         }
     }); //add spacekey event listener to document```
````

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: yeah, you are right next time I'll try to do my best to explain.
 thanks for your notice

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use event.preventDefault() inside keypress event Listener to prevent the Button Click event from getting triggered on keypress

e.g

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        try {
            // if expression is not evaluated then catch block will be executed
            screen.value = eval(screen.value);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            screen.value = 'Invalid Operation';
        }
       
    }
})
```